# CP doesn't recognize update from 2.7.3 to 2.7.4

Tags: updates, craft2, auto-updates

I have a site running Craft 2.7.3. My update flow is to make sure that my development branch is up to date (with no outstanding commits) and that my local db is up to date with production.

I then log in to my development site (site.localhost) and click the Update button. Changes are tested. I then commit the updated files and merge/push to staging and then to production.

Occasionally, updating staging and production will require visiting /admin to trigger a db update. This doesn't seem to be the case with the update from 2.7.3 to 2.7.4.

So, development has been updated to 2.7.4. I then committed and pushed to staging. However, when I log in to the CP on staging, I still see an update badge and the system is telling me that I need to update to 2.7.4.

I have verified that the files changed as a result of updating to 2.7.4 have been deployed to the server. Specifically, I can see that `craft/app/Info.php` defines the `CRAFT_VERSION` constant as 2.7.4. When I log into the staging db and check the `craft_info` table, I see that the value in the `version` column is still 2.7.3.

I have subsequently clicked the "check for updates" links in the CP multiple times, but the system never recognizes the update to 2.7.4.

For what it's worth, I have also used Settings > Clear Caches just in case, but that hasn't had any effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Is opcache enabled on this server (or any other PHP byte-level caching extension)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @BradBell. Unfortunately (fortunately?), it appears that the client used the Update button to move the system to 2.7.4. I could revert staging to 2.7.3, but that would also mean reverting to PHP 5.5. It seems likely that opcache was enabled since this is a relatively old server that was serving our first Craft site on PHP 5.x. I'll keep an eye on this site next time we need to update.